# TSQL cursor translation to PostgreSQL "query has no destination for result"

Tags: postgresql, loops

I inherited some code that was originally in TSQL that was poorly translated into PostgreSQL.  I am tasked with getting the code to work after the contractor did a terrible job of translation.  I don't know if the first insert loop could be rewritten to be a straight forward insert.  Right now it sort of works.  Anyway...

This code is intended to be run as one block against a Postgres database using SSRS.  When I run the entire code block against the database in DBeaver I get:

`SQL Error [42601]: ERROR: query has no destination for result data  Hint: If you want to discard the results of a SELECT, use PERFORM instead. Where: PL/pgSQL function inline_code_block line 40 at SQL statement`

If I run the create table and loop/cursor it first and then run the select it returns a result.  Is there a way to run it all at once without using a stored proc or function?  Code below:

```
do
$$
    declare
        _currentRow  record;
        _refcur      refcursor;
    begin
        drop table if exists "allActionItemsWithTempSalesPersons";
        create temp table "allActionItemsWithTempSalesPersons"  --select * from "allActionItemsWithTempSalesPersons"
        (
            "ID"              int,
            "SalesPersonID"   int,
            "CustomerID"      int,
            "ActionTypeID"    int,
            "Subject"         text,
            "ActionDate"      timestamp without time zone,
            "DurationMintues" int,
            "PriorityID"      int,
            "ResultTypeID"    int,
            "Note"            text,
            "StageId"         int,
            "ActionCloseDate" timestamp without time zone,
            "LUEmployeeID"    int,
            "LUDate"          timestamp without time zone
        );
--Get all action items with temp sales persons handled
        call dbo."HF_SalesPersonActionList_GetActionItemsBySalesPersonId"('0', '3', _refcur);
        loop
            fetch from _refcur into _currentRow;
            EXIT WHEN NOT found;
            INSERT INTO "allActionItemsWithTempSalesPersons"("ID", "SalesPersonID", "CustomerID", "ActionTypeID",
                                                              "Subject", "ActionDate", "DurationMintues", "PriorityID",
                                                              "ResultTypeID", "Note", "StageId", "ActionCloseDate",
                                                              "LUEmployeeID", "LUDate")
            VALUES (_currentRow."ID", _currentRow."SalesPersonID", _currentRow."CustomerID", _currentRow."ActionTypeID",
                    _currentRow."Subject", _currentRow."ActionDate", _currentRow."DurationMintues",
                    _currentRow."PriorityID", _currentRow."ResultTypeID", _currentRow."Note",
                    _currentRow."StageId", _currentRow."ActionCloseDate", _currentRow."LUEmployeeID",
                    _currentRow."LUDate");
        end loop;

        select Emp."FirstName" || ' ' || Emp."LastName"       AS "SalesPerson",
               coalesce("Club"."Name", '')                    AS "Club",
               "Customer"."DisplayName"                       AS "Name",
               SAL."ActionDate"                               AS "ActionDate",
               CASE
                   WHEN "Customer"."IsLead" THEN 'Lead'
                   ELSE dbo."HF_fn_GetMemberType"("Customer"."MemberType")
                   END                                        AS "MemberType",
               act."Description"                              AS "Action",
               SAL."Subject"                                  AS "Subject",
               coalesce("Priority"."Description", '')         AS "Priority",
               coalesce("Stages"."Description", '')           AS "Stage",
               coalesce("Source"."Description", '')           AS "Source",
               (CASE "Customer"."PreferredPhone"
                    WHEN 'M' THEN "Customer"."CellPhone"
                    WHEN 'W' THEN "Customer"."WorkPhone"
                    WHEN 'H' THEN "Customer"."HomePhone" END) AS "PreferredPhone",
               coalesce ("Customer"."Email", '')              AS "Email",
               "Customer"."ID"                                AS "CustomerId",
               "Customer"."BarcodeID"                         AS "MemberId",
               coalesce(RT."Description", '')                 AS "Result",
               SAL."Note"                                     AS "Notes"
        FROM "allActionItemsWithTempSalesPersons" SAL
                 INNER JOIN dbo."Action" act         ON SAL."ActionTypeID" = act."ID"
                 INNER JOIN dbo."Employee" Emp       ON SAL."SalesPersonID" = Emp."ID"
                 INNER JOIN dbo."Customer"           ON SAL."CustomerID" = "Customer"."ID"
                 LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo."ResultType" RT ON SAL."ResultTypeID" = RT."ID"
                 LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo."Club"          ON "Club"."ID" = "Customer"."ClubNumber"
                 LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo."Stages"        ON "Customer"."StageId" = "Stages"."ID"
                 LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo."Priority"      ON SAL."PriorityID" = "Priority"."PriorityID"
                 LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo."Source"        ON "Customer"."SourceID" = "Source"."ID"
        WHERE SAL."ActionDate" >= now()::date
          AND SAL."ActionDate" < (now() + interval '2 day')::date
          AND "Customer"."ClubNumber" = 2 /* use 2 for debugging ? --@clubId */
        ORDER BY SAL."ActionDate", 
                 Emp."FirstName" || ' ' || Emp."LastName";
    end;
$$
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The error message `Hint` tells you what to do use [Perform](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-GENERAL-SQL) example.

Comment: Make `HF_SalesPersonActionList_GetActionItemsBySalesPersonId` a set returning function, then you don't need a loop or PL/pgSQL to begin with - you can simply use the function's result as the source of your INSERT statement. Or even better: ditch the useless temp table and use the function directly in the FROM clause of your final SELECT.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I have no idea how to do those in PostgreSQL.  I'm trying to cobble this together from the dumpster fire of half written contractor code and internet examples.